# How to validate read only field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework, readonly

I'm trying to add a vote functionality to the code found in [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#tutorial) of Django Rest Framework. On top of Snippet model, I added a Vote model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    snippet = models.ForeignKey(Snippet, related_name='votes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

In my serializer, I'm trying to validate the fact that user cannot vote more than once and cannot vote for his own snippet:

```
class VoteSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    voter = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='voter.username',validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Vote.objects.all(), message=already_voted)])
    snippet = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Snippet.objects.all())

    def validate(self, data):
        snippet = data.get('snippet')
        voter = data.get('voter')
        if voter==data['snippet'].owner:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(u"Voter cannot vote for himself.")
        return data
```

Voter field must be read-only. Problem is that ReadOnlyField is not available in data structure. How can I validate with read only field?

EDIT: here is my view

```
class VoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """

    queryset = Vote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                      IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(voter=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your serializer you already have access to current user with `self.context['request'].user`:

so your code should be something like this:

```
if self.context['request'].user == data['snippet'].owner:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(u"Voter cannot vote for himself.")
```

so you can remove the `perform_create` and use this istead